# How can I prove a Thermodynamic identity using rules for partial derivatives

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative, mathematical-physics

I want to prove that:

```
(∂S/∂V) T = (∂P/∂T) V
```

I can only use the Rules for partial derivation and the

```
Heat capacity C definition
Compressibility B 
and volumentric thermal expansion coefficient
```

Can someone give me a hint how can I start, which part should I change or what should I subsitute?

Comment: Do you know the relationship (or equations of state) between $S, T, V, P$?

Comment: @CheeHan Yes, but the thing is I dont understand how this can be proved, I am very confused

Comment: Can you include that relationship? There's nothing we can do now as it stands because we don't know the relations between all the variables.